# PHP if random code exists in database regenerate random code

Tags: php, random

I'm attempting to create a PHP script that will create a random code and check it against a database to see if it exists. I'd like it to check that if it exists then generate another `createRandomCode()` and check it.

Unsure how to proceed with looping until the number of rows are 0.

```
function createRandomCode($length='6'){ 
    $chars = "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz023456789"; 
    srand((double)microtime()*1000000); 
    $i = 0; 
    $code= ''; 
    while ($i++ < $length){ 
        $code = $code. substr($chars, rand() % 33, 1);  
    } 
    return $code; 
}

$shorturl = createRandomCode();

$q = $db - > query("SELECT * FROM maps WHERE url='".$shorturl.
    "'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0) {

    $arr = json_encode($arr);
    echo $arr;
}
```

Comment: Please also read up about race conditions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like a good candidate for a [do...while loop](https://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php):

```
do {
    $shorturl = createRandomCode();
    $q = $db->query("SELECT * FROM maps WHERE url='".$shorturl."'");
} while(mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0);
```

Comment: How would I proceed when `mysqli_num_rows === 0`

Comment: @Donald After the loop, `$shorturl` will contain a unique random code. I assume you'd want to insert it into the database at that point.

Comment: I went searching around for the best way to do this and this one is the best.  Very elegant and simple.

Answer (score 1):

```php
function regenerateCode(){

    global $connection;

    do{

        $serial2 = rand(0,7);

        $check_code = "SELECT * FROM `voters` WHERE `serial` = '$serial2'";

        $run_check_code = mysqli_query($connection,$check_code);

        $count = mysqli_num_rows($run_check_code);

    } while( $count > 0 );

    return $serial2;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.